# Perl 6 error: Malformed UTF-8

Tags: http, utf-8, raku

right now, I'm learning Perl 6; my first project is to make an HTTP client .. I get an error and I do not understand why

```
Malformed UTF-8 at line 1 col 45
  in method new at main.p6 line 13
  in block <unit> at main.p6 line 43
```

I think it comes from the port variable, but I'm not sure
Here is all of my perl6 code:

```
class Request 
{
    has     $!method;
    has     $!path;
    has     $!version;
    has     @!headers;
    has     $!socket;
    has     $.response is rw;

    method      new(:$method, :$path, :$host, :$port, :$version = "HTTP/1.1")
    {
        my $socket = IO::Socket::INET.new(:$host, :$port);
        return self.bless(:$method, :$path, :$version, :$socket);
    }

    submethod   BUILD(:$!method, :$!path, :$!version, :$!socket){}

    method      setHeader($name, $value)
    {
        my %header = name => $name, value => $value;
        @!headers.push({%header});
    }

    method      toString
    {
        my $request = "$!method $!path $!version\r\n";
        for @!headers -> %_ {
            $request ~= %_{'name'} ~ ": " ~ %_{'value'} ~ "\r\n";
        }
        $request ~ "\r\n";
    }

    method      send($i = 1)
    {
        say "Request send!";
        $!socket.print($.toString());
        say $!socket.recv for 0..$i;
    }
}
my $host = "127.0.0.1";
my Int $port = 58002;
my $request = Request.new(:method("GET"), :path("/"), :$host, :$port);

$request.setHeader("host", $host);
$request.setHeader("Accept-Language", "fr");
$request.send(2);
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is receiving valid utf8 data from the server? Also why is it named `toString` and not the more sensical `Str`?

Comment: If you have copy and pasted that code from somewhere, the "/" or some of the other characters might have some codification problem. Please make sure from your editor that it can be saved to UTF8

Comment: I only had 7-8 minutes to write my answer -- only enough to take your code in at a superficial level. I was hopeful it wasn't so useless it would annoy or frustrate you but to my surprise you've actually accepted it! Did it really explain all you needed to know and/or have you fixed your problem? As I got to the end of writing my answer I noticed the code I quoted is line 42, not 43, and that "line 1 col 45" is confusing given it's about data, not code, but it doesn't say that and rest of error message is line X of code. I'd love to hear your critique of the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer may not be helpful, might be annoying, but I can delete it later today if it was and it's all I've got and I have to run.

I don't know if you understand the error message, but let's cover that first.

```
Malformed UTF-8 at line 1 col 45
  in method new at main.p6 line 13
  in block <unit> at main.p6 line 43
```

This means that during execution of the last line in the message, line 43 of your *code*, something went wrong:

```
my $request = Request.new(:method("GET"), :path("/"), :$host, :$port);
```

The compiler noticed that execution of that last line involved a path that went through another line in your code, line 13:

```
    return self.bless(:$method, :$path, :$version, :$socket);
```

So that helps better pinpoint the line during execution of which the error occurred.

`.bless` is a method call. It's called on `self` which refers to the invocant passed to the method which you can assume is an object of the class in which the method call appears, namely the class you're defining `Request`.

Your code doesn't specify what class `Request` inherits from (using `is`) so it inherits from `Any`. The `bless` for `Any` is inherited from [`Mu`'s](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Any#%28Mu%29_method_bless).

which is [this code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Mu.pm6#L134) in the Rakudo compiler:

```
method bless(*%attrinit) {
    nqp::create(self).BUILDALL(Empty, %attrinit);
}
```

So during execution of that code, Perl 6 attempted to read some UTF8 and encountered an invalid character at col 45 of the very first line of some *data* it tried to read.

So that's the best I can say about why, without seeing your data.